Do eddy currents in a rotor core of an induction motor create torque proportional to the coil current of a squirrel cage?
In a rotor of an induction motor, the core plates and wire coil conductors have non-zero thicknesses. Therefore, eddy currents non-zero too. And they approximately proportional to the coil current of a squirrel cage. Do eddy currents generate a proportional torque?
If a squirrel cage is replaced with a solid cylinder while approximately maintaining the mass of the conductor, then the currents within it would correspond to eddy currents. Would the relationship between the torque and the power losses in the rotor be preserved? Or would energy losses increase and torque decreases because the currents would flow along a different path?


Do eddy currents generate a proportional torque?

The direction of eddy currents are largely perpendicular to the direction of current in the rotor and, because the rotor current modifies the main field from the stator in order to create a rotational force, we can see that eddy currents contribute virtually nothing to torque. If they did wouldn't we just use a big blob of metal instead of a finely crafted rotor?
Well, actually, we can make an induction motor with a solid rotor but, they are at a disadvantage compared to squirrel cage rotors at conventional rotational speeds. They only come into their own where significantly higher speeds are required and a squirrel cage might fall apart. A Performance Comparison of Different Rotor Types for High-Speed Induction
Motors might be of interest.

If a squirrel cage is replaced with a solid cylinder while
approximately maintaining the mass of the conductor, then the currents
within it would correspond to eddy currents.

No, there would still be conventional torque-generating current (as seen in a squirrel cage motor). But, of course, the eddy currents would be significantly greater.

Would the relationship between the torque and the power losses in the
rotor be preserved? Or would energy losses increase and torque
decreases because the currents would flow along a different path?

The latter.

Thanks for the explanations and the link to the article. The cylinder with conductivity only along the shaft instead of a squirrel cage would be an ideal coil of rotor? On condition to the preservation of the conducting rings along the cylinder ends?

This cannot be answered within the highly constrained environment of the comment section and, it goes beyond your original question a fair way.
